# Construct grid of points in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Consider two dimensions `(x,y)`.

I want to construct in Matlab the grid of points such that `-0.8<x<0.1` and `0.1<y<0.9`. From such a grid I want to delete all the points such that `-0.7<=x<=0` and `0.2<=y<=0.8`.

I use "grid precision" equal to `0.001`.

Here my code which does not seem to do what I want

```
%outside square
xgrid=(-0.8+0.001:0.001:0.1-0.001);
ygrid=(0.1+0.001:0.001:0.9-0.001);
[p,q] = meshgrid(xgrid, ygrid);
grid = [p(:) q(:)];
%inside square
xgrid1=(-0.7:0.001:0);
xgrid1=(0.2:0.001:0.8);
[p,q] = meshgrid(xgrid1, ygrid1);
grid1 = [p(:) q(:)];
%delete inside square from outside square
grid(ismember(grid,grid1, 'rows'),:)=[];
```

`Ismember` does not seem to recognise that all the points in `grid1` are in `grid`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this code with comments describing what to do

```
% Define grid precision, h, for more clarity and easier editing
h = 1e-3;
% Specify xgrid and ygrid using 2 parts each
xgrid = [-0.8+h:h:-0.7-h, 0+h:h:0.1];
ygrid = [0.1+h:h:0.2-h, 0.8+h:h:0.9-h];
% Make grid and use it to get coordinate pairs
[p,q] = meshgrid(xgrid, ygrid);
grid = [p(:) q(:)];
```

You are trying to create a large grid, then remove an internal square from it. The above code creates just the resulting matrix, never making the internal square in the first place.

---

**Edit**

OP clarified that only coordinates where `-0.7<=x<=0.0` AND `0.2<=y<=0.8` should be removed, the above is for the "OR" case. Below is for the "AND" case as desired...

```
% Define grid precision, h, for more clarity and easier editing
h = 1e-3;
% Specify xgrid and ygrid using 2 parts each
xgrid = [-0.8+h:h:0.1];
ygrid = [0.1+h:h:0.9-h];
% Make grid and use it to get coordinate pairs
[xx, yy] = meshgrid(xgrid, ygrid);
% Turn grids into column vectors
xx = xx(:); yy = yy(:);
% Logical indexing for where range removal condition is met
idx = (xx >= -0.7 & xx <= 0.0) & (yy >= 0.2 & yy <= 0.8)
% grid is all values of xx and yy which are NOT true in idx, so ~idx
grid = [xx(~idx) yy(~idx)];
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure that it does what I want. From the original square containing all points such that `-0.8<x<0.1` AND `0.1<y<0.9` I want to delete all points such that `-0.7<=x<=0` AND `02<=y<=0.8`. It think your code excludes in general all points such that `-0.7<=x<=0`, for example. If you look at my code, what I want is the area between the outside and the inside square.

Comment: Thanks. I think `ygrid = [0.1+h:h:0.9-h];` and not `ygrid = [0.1+h:h:0.8-h];`

Comment: @user3285148 I've made that edit, consider accepting this answer if it does what you want